# Pivot and automatic inclusion of new row nr data in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I needed some guidance from your more experience excel pros. I have two sheets in my excel file.

1. Data
2. Pivot Data

I have my data in the "Data" sheet and I have created a Pivot sheet for sheet Data.

Everyweek, I delete my data in the Data sheet and paste new data.With this, my rows become more.  to update my pivots, I need to go to data source and update it so it include all the rows.

Is there something I can do or write so the pivots automatically adjust to the size of the new paste data in the Data sheet?

If before deleting the data, it was on row 400, I then paste new data and the row number is now 800, how can I automate this process rather than going to each pivot and updating manually to the new row number so it captures all the new data?

Answer (score 0):

Change your Data Source range to exclude row numbers, so say:

```
Sheet3!$A:$D
```

instead of:

```
Sheet3!$A1:$D400
```

This will however introduce a row in your PT of `(blank)` (if not already present there), though you might filter to hide that row.

Comment: Thank you for your response. One question, what were you thinking about when you say "PT of (Bank)?